# How can I speed up debugging in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'd like to be able to speed-up the debugging process when building Sencha Touch apps.  At the moment I have to disable caching as any changes I make to the source would not get updated when refreshing the application and I also want to persist breakpoints in Chrome.

How can I both cache the files that are unlikely to change but refresh those that do?

Currently, when I press Ctrl+F5, it takes 4-5 seconds to load the app.  It's loading all the Sencha Touch required .js files as well as any for the app itself.  I think what I would like to do is cache on a path basis, so any files on the sencha touch source folder are cached and not re-loaded, but app files aren't.

Answer (score 0):

try using an application cache manifest you can learn to configure one [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). Application cache is not for folders though but for files so you have to include all files that you want to be cached permanantly.